# Conflicting types with parameters in a function in C

Tags: c, parameter-passing

I am trying to do something as simple as pass parameters into a function but I seem to be having a lot of trouble, and I can't seem to figure out how to fix it. FYI this is for a homework assignment that is going to be a basic assembly language simulator.

Here is the code

```
char cmd_char;
char leadChar;
int location;
short int value;

words_read = sscanf(cmd_buffer, "%d %c%hx x%hx", &cmd_char, &leadChar, &location, &value);

...

done = execute_command(cmd_char, cpu, leadChar, location, value);

...

int execute_command(char cmd_char, CPU *cpu, char leadChar, int location, int value)
{
    ...
}
```

The string being inputted into sscanf(...) will either be:

```
m x305f x002c
r r6 x10a5
r r3 x0014
j x3030
```

There is no problem with scanning the proper values, but when I added the variables leadChar, location, and value as parameters to execute_command, I have been unable to sucessfully call it. See the errors below.

The Error messages

```
Lab10.c:42:46: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' be                                   fore '(' token
 int execute_command(char cmd_char, CPU *cpu, (char) void, (int) void, (int) voi                                   d);
                                              ^
Lab10.c:42:59: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' be                                   fore '(' token
 int execute_command(char cmd_char, CPU *cpu, (char) void, (int) void, (int) voi                                   d);

Lab10.c:277:5: error: conflicting types for 'execute_command'
 int execute_command(char cmd_char, CPU *cpu, char leadChar, int location, int v                                   alue)
     ^
Lab10.c:278:1: note: an argument type that has a default promotio                                   n can't match an empty parameter name list declaration
 {
 ^
Lab10.c:265:20: note: previous implicit declaration of 'execute_c                                   ommand' was here
             done = execute_command(cmd_char, cpu, leadChar, location, value);
                    ^
                                                    ^
Lab10_BenShaughnessy.c:42:71: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' be                                   fore '(' token
 int execute_command(char cmd_char, CPU *cpu, (char) void, (int) void, (int) voi                                   d);
```

Comment: Does your function declaration matches your definition?

Comment: Declare `int execute_command(char cmd_char, CPU *cpu, char leadChar, int location, int value);` before first use or include appropriate header file.

Answer (score 1):

In the line:

```
words_read = sscanf(cmd_buffer, "%d %c%hx x%hx", &cmd_char, &leadChar, &location, &value);
```

you tell `sscanf()` that `&location` is a `short *`, but it isn't; it is an `int *`.  You need to change the conversion specification to `%x`.  GCC should tell you about this problem, though you might need to twist its arm gently (`-Wall` is recommended; IIRC, `-Wformat` is the specific option that's needed, but `-Wall` is better if you're not using it already).

In fact, as [chux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux) points out in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27286900/conflicting-types-with-parameters-in-a-function-in-c/27287061?noredirect=1#comment43041162_27287061), there's also a type mismatch between `%d` and `&cmd_char`, too.  Thus, you really need:

```
words_read = sscanf(cmd_buffer, "%c %c%d x%hx", &cmd_char, &leadChar, &location, &value);
```

And if you're not sure whether there might be leading blanks on the string, then add a space before the first `%c`.  Note that even though you write a space in the format string, `sscanf()` treats that as optional white space, so the format will accept both of these:

```
m x305f x002c
mx305fx002c
```

and various other inputs too.

Comment: Suspect `"%d ..."` should be `"%c ..."` also

Comment: ... or `" %c ..."` (with leading space)